# cocoa application changing mouse cursor?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouse

I have a cocoa application that has a view which is clickable. I cannot figure out how to change the cursor when the user mouses over it. I want to do this so that the user knows that they can click on it. I know this should be very simple, but I have not been able to find anything via google or stackoverflow. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, not this?

[Cocoa: change cursor when it's over an NSButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925580/cocoa-change-cursor-when-its-over-an-nsbutton)

> [yourButton addCursorRect:[yourButton bounds] cursor:[theCursorYouWant]];

(Quote from Mark)

Answer (score 3):

This is a relatively simple thing to do using `NSView`'s tracking areas methods in conjunction with the `NSCursor` class to change the cursor. In general, the way you do this is set up a tracking area for your view, and when you get `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` updates from the tracking area, you can update the cursor.

Check out the [NSView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) and the [NSCursor Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCursor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.