# How to force the cursor to be an "arrowCursor" when it hovers a NSButton that is inside a NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton, nscursor, nstrackingarea

Okay, here is the problem:
I have a `NSTextView` and I add my custom `NSButton` using:

```
[_textView addSubview:button];
```

Then, inside my `NSButton` subclass, I have (along with the `NSTrackingArea` stuff):

```
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)event{
     [[NSCursor arrowCursor] set];
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
     [[NSCursor arrowCursor] set];
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
     [[NSCursor arrowCursor] set];
}

- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
     [[NSCursor arrowCursor] set];
}
```

But when I hover it, the cursor remains the same `IBeamCursor` (because it's a `NSTextView`). Only when I press the button, the cursor gets updated. And then, when I move the mouse, still inside the button, the cursor goes back to the `IBeamCursor`.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried implementing `cursorUpdate:`, as specified in ["Managing Cursor-Update Events"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH8-SW10)?

Comment: yes, but the outcome is the same

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding a tracking area that only tracks enter/exit events seems to be not enough for `NSTextView` subviews. Somehow the textview always wins and sets it's  `IBeamCursor`.

You can try to always enable tracking for mouse *move* events (`NSTrackingMouseMoved`) when adding the tracking area in your `NSButton` subclass:

```
#import "SSWHoverButton.h"

@interface SSWHoverButton()
{
    NSTrackingArea* trackingArea;
}

@end

@implementation SSWHoverButton

- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent*)theEvent
{
    [[NSCursor arrowCursor] set];
}

- (void)updateTrackingAreas
{
    if(trackingArea != nil)
    {
        [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
    }
    NSTrackingAreaOptions opts = (NSTrackingMouseMoved|NSTrackingActiveAlways);
    trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds]
                                                 options:opts
                                                   owner:self
                                                userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}

@end
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, but unfortunately it's not working :/

Comment: Hi Pedro,
I just tried it in a sample Xcode project. Works like a charm here (10.8). Did you use exactly the subclass I posted above? If so, did you instantiate it instead of your own?

Comment: Ooops, pardon me! It's working now, and tbh, I haven't changed anything :P Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Apparently solution mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925580/cocoa-change-cursor-when-its-over-an-nsbutton does not work

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5 variant:

```
import Cocoa

class InsideTextButton: NSButton {

    var trackingArea: NSTrackingArea?

    override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
        NSCursor.arrow.set()
    }

    override func updateTrackingAreas() {
        if let area = trackingArea {
            removeTrackingArea(area)
        }

        trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: self.bounds, options: [.mouseMoved, .activeAlways], owner: self, userInfo: nil)

        if let area = trackingArea {
            addTrackingArea(area)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        if let area = trackingArea {
            removeTrackingArea(area)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly.